# Redirect to page submit action not working in Safari browser

Tags: sitecore-forms

I designed one contact form in my website and given 1) `Send Email` and 2) `Redirect to page` submit actions to submit button.

Form is working in all the browsers except Safari.

When I submitted form in Safari browser `Redirect to page` submit action is not working.

Comment: Which version of Sitecore and Safari? Which OS?

Comment: Sitecore version is 9.1, Safari version is 12.1 and OS is MAC

Comment: Have you tried the same on clean Sitecore instance? If it doesn't work there, just raise a Sitecore Support bug. If it does work there, you have something wrong with your solution and without further knowledge about all your changes we won't be able to help you.

Comment: Are you embedding the form elsewhere as an iframe form?

Comment: @FredricFoo, no i'm not embedding

Comment: @MarekMusielak, there is no add on changes in the form. created a simple form with single line text boxes and one submit button with default submit actions Send Email and Redirect to page. when i click on submit button Send email is fired and received email but redirect to page is not working simply staying in the same page

Comment: So it's a bug in Sitecore, right? You need to raise a Sitecore Support ticket...

Answer (score 4):

I assume you submit the form via Ajax.

We had exactly the same problem before when the form submission is done via Ajax. There is an "Is Ajax" check box in the form that you can turn off.

We actually raised that as a Sitecore ticket a while ago. Despite it being a bug, they recommended a workaround to just turn off the ajax and use normal POST request.